# Validate text box to limited numeric input

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, textbox, keypress

I have text box in c# windows form. Here I'm limiting the input of the tsextbox only to numeric values.

```
private void txtpref02_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)))
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

I have two other requirements.

1. I want to enable the text box to accept only one digit. It should be 0,1,2 or 3.
2. How to enable backspace in the code given above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I'd do it:

```
private void txtpref02_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch(e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.D0:
        case Keys.NumPad0:
        case Keys.D1:
        case Keys.NumPad1:
        case Keys.D2:
        case Keys.NumPad2:
        case Keys.D3:
        case Keys.NumPad3:
        case Keys.Back:
        case Keys.Delete:
            return;
        default:
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            e.Handled = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

Also, you can set the `MaxLength` property to `1` to limit the number of characters as you've indicated.

**Please note:** this code is using the `KeyDown` event, not the `KeyPress` event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void txtpref02_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) || e.KeyChar == (char)8)
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

To accept only one character, you can use the `MaxLength` property of the `TextBox`.

Comment: Now backspace works, max length also works. Thanks a lot. Is there anyway to limit the entered digit to be only one from this (0,1,2,3) set.